# Linux Mint on Dell XPS 9570 - Power Issues, Inconsistent power-on

Tags: ubuntu, linux-mint, grub, power-management

This is my first time posting on a linux help site, so be gentle. I've installed Linux Mint 19.3 "Tricia" on a 2018 Dell XPS 9570, 15" laptop.

People have addressed this in many posts, including this one: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/XPS-15-9570-and-Ubuntu/td-p/6096817

My main issue right now is very inconsistent power-on behavior. If I reboot, or push the power button to shut the laptop off, it may take anywhere from 1 - 30 attempts to power the laptop on before it will actually boot.

Here is my relevant grub setting:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nouveau.modeset=0 acpi_rev_override=1 mem_sleep_default=deep"
```

And I'm using nvidia driver 435, kernel 5.3.0-40-generic

Please help! Love the machine but deathly afraid of it running out of battery.

Comment: Upvote for posting the link. I'm running an XPS15 9550 on Ubuntu and the power management issues are very frustrating

Comment: Presumably you've run `sudo grub-install` after making the changes to your `/etc/default/grub` file?

Comment: @Mark you bet I have. Very frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Power on is handled way before the operating system even gets a say on the machine. Broken/messed up BIOS, flaky hardware would be my first guesses.